# InvalidStateError: "An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable" in basic Google Map tutorial example

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, firefox

I have an XML, which is transformed to HTML via an XSLT. The XML is able to contain JavaScript, and it translates this correctly to HTML, as I do in many other pages as well. It just does not work with GoogleMaps, and I suspect, my JavaScript is faulty somewhere.

The relevant sections of the resulting HTML look like posted below.

What's happening in the HTML/in the Scripts:

- The API is loaded from googleapis.com
- A div with the ID map_canvas is created.
- A function start() is defined, which is started via `<body
  onload="start();">`.
- In this function, a variable map_canvas is created and passed the
  reference to the div object named map_canvas.
- To control, that this step worked, I give the div the new background
  color red.
- It works.
- Next, I'd want to create the variable var_options and set initial
  values for center, zoom, and mapTypeId.
- To control, that this step worked, I give the div the new background
  color blue.
- This does not work, it stays red.
- Hence, this instruction was not executed.
- So I check if I can access the object `google.maps` at all.
- if so, I give the div the new background color green.
- This works, so I can access this object.
- Cross check: If I comment out the statement loading the API, the
  color does not change.

To me, this looks like the following is faulty somewhere.

```
    var map_options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.54, -78.54),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
```

But after several hours I still cannot figure out what it is.

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript">
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function start()
        {   
            var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');

// If the element can be located, we make it green. Checked.
// If we give the function another name than start, it won't be executed. Checked.
map_canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'green';

            if(typeof google.maps != 'undefined') {
// If the google.maps object exists, we make the canvas red. Checked.
// If the API was not loaded from googleapis (commented out), it will stay green. 
map_canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            }

// So why does the following not work?
            var map_options = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.54, -78.54),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
// Not arriving here:
map_canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';

// Before going on, I want to solve above problem, so this is commented out.
//            var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
// map_canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
        }
        </script>
    </head>


    <body onload="start();">
        ...
        <div style="width: 400px; height: 224px;" id="map_canvas"></div>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error do you get in the console?

Comment: The code gave me error that sensor has to be either true or false. I tested around a bit and changing your googleapis url to `<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript">` helps. At least it doesn't give errors after it and the element turns blue (as supposed?). I removed `amp;` from the front of the sensor parameter.

Comment: Thanks Puuskis. This was a copy-paste rmnant, originally I used key=xxx, but I later learned, that it's not neccessary any longer. - However, my code still does not work, i.e., the div stays red.

Comment: @Bergi. It refers to line 9 of the loaded js, wich reads: '' type="text/javascript"><' + '/script>');'. It says: [13:54:46.604] InvalidStateError: "An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable @ http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false:9"

Comment: What browser (version) are you using? Looks like this is a browser-specific error.

Comment: @Bergi - Thank you, this solved the problem! Firefox 21.0 is the evildoer. IE 10 has no problems with it. - To think, that I changed to FF to avoid those constant IE problems! Now I need to google if there is a fix for this, I don't assume I am the only one having this problem...

Comment: Well, changing the browser does not really solve the underlying problem… My google searches showed some problems with FF Ajax throwing this exception, seems to be a bug in the GM script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found [this Google page](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/callback/callback_delayed.html) ([webarchive](https://web.archive.org/web/20160503155832/http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/callback/callback_delayed.html)). It seems undocumented, though. Click on the button. Works on both FF and IE. Check out the markup and the Javascript, it loads the map via a callback.

Thanks for putting me on the right track.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Dynamic Loading</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function handleApiReady() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  }

  function appendBootstrap() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=handleApiReady";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
  <input type="button" value="Load Bootstrap + API" onclick="appendBootstrap()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:400px; height:400px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 16):

I find the most common cause of this error is simply an invalid img src.

Answer (score 4):

My error was something similar (which is why I found this post), but only in Internet Explorer (version 11):

```
File: eval code (401), Line: 39, Column: 304
```

This was caused because I used svg-images as markers:

```
var marker = map.addMarker({
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    lng: position.coords.longitude,
    icon : {
        url : '/images/marker.svg'
    }
});
```

Switching to png-images instead of svg solved my problem!

Comment: Try to add height and width to your SVG. 
See for more info : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23923607/custom-markers-in-google-maps-not-showing-up-in-firefox#answer-24280941

Comment: Thanks @Promo, that was exactly what I needed. Your comment could be a separate answer if you ask me.