# What can cause a Promise rejected with 'InvalidStateError' here?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

What can cause a Promise rejected with `'InvalidStateError'` here ?

```
const SERVICE_WORKER_VERSION = "3.0.0"; // is updated in the build when things change
const CACHE_VERSION = SERVICE_WORKER_VERSION;

const fillServiceWorkerCache = function () {
    /* save in cache some static ressources 
    this happens before activation */
    return caches.open(CACHE_VERSION).then(function(cache) {
        return cache.addAll(ressourcesToSaveInCache);
    });
};

self.addEventListener("install", function (event) {
    /*event.waitUntil takes a promise that should resolves successfully*/
    event.waitUntil(fillServiceWorkerCache().then(function() {
        return self.skipWaiting();
    }));
});
```

On Firefox version 52 the following error occurs: `Service worker event waitUntil() was passed a promise that rejected with 'InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable'.` The service worker is killed and removed after that. It works fine with Chrome. `ressourcesToSaveInCache` is an array of relative URLs.

Edit changing it to

```
event.waitUntil(
    fillServiceWorkerCache()
    .then(skipWaiting)
    .catch(skipWaiting)
);
```

and the service worker registers ! However `fillServiceWorkerCache` rejected , which is a big deal (no offline cache). Now the question is why does `fillServiceWorkerCache` reject, and what is the error message trying to tell ?

Edit inspired by Hosar's answer:

```
const fillServiceWorkerCache2 = function () {
    return caches.open(CACHE_VERSION).then(function (cache) {
        return Promise.all(
            ressourcesToSaveInCache.map(function (url) {
                return cache.add(url).catch(function (reason) {
                    return console.log(url + "failed: " + String(reason));
                })
            })
        );
    });
};
```

This version propagates a promise in the return chain, making the `waitUntil()` actually wait for it. It will not cache and also not reject for individual ressources that failed to be added in the cache.

Edit 2: After fixing invalid relative URLs in ressourcesToSaveInCache, the error was gone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most probably is that an **img src** is not valid, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212508/invalidstateerror-an-attempt-was-made-to-use-an-object-that-is-not-or-is-no-l/19748899). 
So, with `cache.addAll` if one of the request is invalid none of the requests will be saved. Better use: `cache.add` as follow:

```
return caches.open('cacheName').then(function(cache) {
      Promise.all(
        ressourcesToSaveInCache.map(function(url){cache.add(url)})
      );
    });
```

In this case all the valid urls will be saved.