# FetchEvent for "[url]" resulted in a network error response: the promise was rejected

Tags: javascript, promise, progressive-web-apps

I am getting those errors and warning in my console after trying to create a PWA - Progressive Web App out of my website using [this](https://medium.com/@aswin_s/score-a-perfect-100-in-lighthouse-audits-part-1-3199163037) tutorial.

> The FetchEvent for
>   "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-4562443-3" resulted in
>   a network error response: the promise was rejected. Promise.then
>   (async) (anonymous) @ service-worker.js:228 service-worker.js:1
>   Uncaught (in promise) fetch failed 1:21 GET
>   https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-4562443-3
>   net::ERR_FAILED The FetchEvent for
>   "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400&display=swap&subset=cyrillic"
>   resulted in a network error response: the promise was rejected.
>   Promise.then (async) (anonymous) @ service-worker.js:228
>   service-worker.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) fetch failed 1:28 GET
>   https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400&display=swap&subset=cyrillic
>   net::ERR_FAILED The FetchEvent for
>   "https://widget.uservoice.com/VuHfPZ0etI2eQ4REt1tiUg.js" resulted in a
>   network error response: the promise was rejected. Promise.then (async)
>   (anonymous) @ service-worker.js:228 service-worker.js:1 Uncaught (in
>   promise) fetch failed 1:894 GET
>   https://widget.uservoice.com/VuHfPZ0etI2eQ4REt1tiUg.js net::ERR_FAILED

It actually works pretty well. I am able to get a fully working PWA icon in Audits in Chrome Dev Tools. Which is great, but after a refresh I am getting all those errors. My `service-worker.js` which is located at root of my website looks like this

```js
"use strict";

const SERVICE_WORKER_VERSION = "REPLACED_WITH_SERVICE_WORKER_VERSION"; // updated with tools/service_worker_version.js (String)
const CACHE_VERSION = SERVICE_WORKER_VERSION;
//const fileNamesToSaveInCache = ["/"];
const HOME = "/";
const OFFLINE_ALTERNATIVE = "/offline";
const fileNamesToSaveInCache = [];
const fileNamesToSaveInCacheProd = [
    OFFLINE_ALTERNATIVE,
    "/",
    "/publics/img/favicon/fav.gif",
    "/publics/css/style.css",
    "/publics/css/searchhelp.css",
    "/publics/css/Helpa.css",
];
const rtcLength = 4; // "rtc/".length;
const rtcFetchDelay = 10000;//ms
const origin = location.origin;
const answerFromfileName = {};
const resolveFromfileName = {};
const rejectFromfileName = {};
const timeOutIdFromfileName = {};
let logLater = [];
// todo put all into single container

const resolveFetchFromPeerToPeer = function (fileName) {
    clearTimeout(timeOutIdFromfileName[fileName]);
    resolveFromfileName[fileName](answerFromfileName[fileName]);
    delete answerFromfileName[fileName];//stop listening
    delete resolveFromfileName[fileName];
    delete rejectFromfileName[fileName];
};

const rejectFetchFromPeerToPeer = function (fileName, reason) {
    if (rejectFromfileName[fileName]) {
        rejectFromfileName[fileName](reason);
        delete resolveFromfileName[fileName];
        delete rejectFromfileName[fileName];
    }
};

const fetchFromPeerToPeer = function (customRequestObject) {
    /*asks all page for a fileName*/

    const fileName = customRequestObject.header.fileName;

    const promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolveFromfileName[fileName] = resolve;
        rejectFromfileName[fileName] = reject;
        if (answerFromfileName.hasOwnProperty(fileName)) {
            resolveFetchFromPeerToPeer(fileName);
        }
        timeOutIdFromfileName[fileName] = setTimeout(function() {
            rejectFetchFromPeerToPeer(fileName, "No answer after 10 seconds");
        }, rtcFetchDelay);
    });

    self.clients.matchAll().then(function(clientList) {
        clientList.forEach(function(client) {
            client.postMessage(customRequestObject);
        });
    });
    return promise;
};

const logInTheUI = (function () {
    //console.log("logInTheUI function exists");
    return function (what) {
        console.log(what);
        self.clients.matchAll().then(function(clientList) {
            clientList.forEach(function(client) {
                client.postMessage({LOG: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(what))});
            });
        });
    };
}());

const logInTheUIWhenActivated = function (what) {
    logLater.push(what);
};

const fetchFromMainServer = function (request, options = {}) {
    /*wrap over fetch. The problem with fetch here, it doesn't reject properly sometimes
    see if statement below*/
    return fetch(request, options).then(function (fetchResponse) {
        // console.log("fetchFromMainServer:", fetchResponse.ok, fetchResponse);
        // logInTheUI([request, options]);
        if ((!fetchResponse) || (!fetchResponse.ok)) {
            return Promise.reject("fetch failed");
        }
        return fetchResponse;
    });
};


const fetchFromCache = function (request) {
    return caches.open(CACHE_VERSION).then(function (cache) {
        return cache.match(request).then(function (CacheResponse) {
            //console.log("fetchFromCache:", CacheResponse.ok, CacheResponse);
            if ((!CacheResponse) || (!CacheResponse.ok)) {
                return Promise.reject("Not in Cache");
            }
            return CacheResponse;
        });
    });
};

const isLocalURL = function (url) {
    return !(String(url).match("rtc"));
};

const fillServiceWorkerCache2 = function () {
    /*It will not cache and also not reject for individual resources that failed to be added in the cache. unlike fillServiceWorkerCache which stops caching as soon as one problem occurs. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41388616/what-can-cause-a-promise-rejected-with-invalidstateerror-here*/
    return caches.open(CACHE_VERSION).then(function (cache) {
        return Promise.all(
            fileNamesToSaveInCache.map(function (url) {
                return cache.add(url).catch(function (reason) {
                    return logInTheUIWhenActivated([url + "failed: " + String(reason)]);
                });
            })
        );
    });
};

const latePutToCache = function (request, response) {
    return caches.open(CACHE_VERSION).then(function(cache) {
        cache.put(request, response.clone());
        return response;
    });
};

const deleteServiceWorkerOldCache = function () {
    return caches.keys().then(function (cacheVersions) {
        return Promise.all(
            cacheVersions.map(function (cacheVersion) {
                if (CACHE_VERSION === cacheVersion) {
                    //console.log("No change in cache");
                } else {
                    //console.log("New SERVICE_WORKER_VERSION of cache, delete old");
                    return caches.delete(cacheVersion);
                }
            })
        );
    });
};

const useOfflineAlternative = function () {
    return fetchFromCache(new Request(OFFLINE_ALTERNATIVE));
};

const isAppPage = function (url) {
    /*appPage does not work offline, and we don't serve it if offline
    returns Boolean*/
    return (origin + HOME) === url;
};

self.addEventListener("install", function (event) {
    /*the install event can occur while another service worker is still active

    waitUntil blocks the state (here installing) of the service worker until the
    promise is fulfilled (resolved or rejected). It is useful to make the service worker more readable and more deterministic

    save in cache some static fileNames
    this happens before activation */
    event.waitUntil(
        fillServiceWorkerCache2()
        .then(skipWaiting)
    );
});

self.addEventListener("activate", function (event) {
    /* about to take over, other service worker are killed after activate, syncronous
    a good moment to clear old cache*/
    event.waitUntil(deleteServiceWorkerOldCache().then(function() {
        //console.log("[ServiceWorker] Skip waiting on install caches:", caches);
        return self.clients.claim();
    }));
});

self.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    const message = event.data;
    /*
    if (message.hasOwnProperty("FUTURE")) {
        console.log(message.FUTURE);
        return;
    }
    */
    const fileName = message.fileName;
    const answer = message.answer;
    answerFromfileName[fileName] = answer;
    //console.log(fileName, answer, resolveFromfileName);
    if (resolveFromfileName.hasOwnProperty(fileName)) {//
        resolveFetchFromPeerToPeer(fileName);
    }
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", function (fetchEvent) {
    /* fetchEvent interface FetchEvent
    see https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#fetch-event-interface
    IMPORTANT: fetchEvent.respondWith must be called inside this handler immediately
    synchronously fetchEvent.respondWith must be called with a response object or a
    promise that resolves with a response object. if fetchEvent.respondWith is called
    later in a callback the browser will take over and asks the remote server directly, do not do that

    why have fetchEvent.respondWith( and not respond with the return value of the callback function ?
    -->
    It allows to do other thing before killing the service worker, like saving stuff in cache
    */
    const request = fetchEvent.request;//Request implements Body;
    //const requestClone = request.clone(); //no need to clone ?
    const url = request.url;
    if (logLater) {
        logLater.forEach(logInTheUI);
        logLater = undefined;
    }
    // logInTheUI(["fetch service worker " + SERVICE_WORKER_VERSION, fetchEvent]);
    // Needs to activate to handle fetch
    if (isLocalURL(url)) {
        //Normal Fetch

        if (request.method === "POST") {
            // logInTheUI(["POST ignored", request]);
            return;
        }

        // logInTheUI(["Normal Fetch"]);
        fetchEvent.respondWith(
            fetchFromCache(request.clone()).then(function (cacheResponse) {
                /* cannot use request again from here, use requestClone */
                //console.log(request, url);
                return cacheResponse;
            }).catch(function (reason) {
                // We don't have it in the cache, fetch it
                // logInTheUI(fetchEvent);
                return fetchFromMainServer(request);
            }).then(function (mainServerResponse) {
                if (isAppPage(url)) {
                    return mainServerResponse;
                }
                return latePutToCache(request, mainServerResponse).catch(
                    function (reason) {
                        /*failed to put in cache do not propagate catch, not important enough*/
                        return mainServerResponse;
                    }
                );

            }).catch(function (reason) {
                if (isAppPage(url)) {
                    //if it is the landing page that is asked
                    return useOfflineAlternative();
                    //todo if we are offline , display /offline directly
                }
                return Promise.reject(reason);
            })
        );
    } else {
        // Peer to peer Fetch
        //console.log(SERVICE_WORKER_VERSION, "rtc fetch" url:", fetchEvent.request.url);
        // request, url are defined
        const method = request.method;
        const requestHeaders = request.headers;

        //logInTheUI(["Special Fetch"]);
        const customRequestObject = {
            header: {
                fileName: url.substring(url.indexOf("rtc/") + rtcLength),
                method
            },
            body: ""
        };
        requestHeaders.forEach(function (value, key) {
            //value, key correct order
            //is there a standard way to use Object.assign with Map like iterables ?
            //todo handle duplicates
            //https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#terminology-headers
            customRequestObject.header[key] = value;
        });

        //console.log(request);
        fetchEvent.respondWith(
            /*should provide the peer the full request*/
            request.arrayBuffer().then(function (bodyAsArrayBuffer) {
                const bodyUsed = request.bodyUsed;
                if (bodyUsed && bodyAsArrayBuffer) {
                    customRequestObject.body = bodyAsArrayBuffer;
                }
            }).catch(function (reason) {
                /*console.log("no body sent, a normal GET or HEAD request has no body",
                reason);*/
            }).then(function (notUsed) {
                return fetchFromPeerToPeer(customRequestObject);
            }).then(function (response) {
                const responseInstance = new Response(response.body, {
                    headers: response.header,
                    status: response.header.status || 200,
                    statusText : response.header.statusText || "OK"
                });

                return responseInstance;
            }).catch(function (error) {
                const responseInstance = new Response(`<html><p>${error}</p></html>`,
                    {
                    headers: {
                        "Content-type": "text/html"
                    },
                    status: 500,
                    statusText : "timedout"
                });

                return responseInstance;
            })
        );
    }

    /*here we could do more with event.waitUntil()*/
});
```

I am guessing the problem comes from loading those external libraries. So, this is my code loading those libraries.

```js
// Include the UserVoice JavaScript SDK (only needed once on a page)
     UserVoice = window.UserVoice || [];
     (function() {
         var uv = document.createElement('script');
         uv.type = 'text/javascript';
         uv.async = true;
         uv.src = '//widget.uservoice.com/VuHfPZ0etI2eQ4REt1tiUg.js';
         var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         s.parentNode.insertBefore(uv, s)
     })();
     //
     // UserVoice Javascript SDK developer documentation:
     // https://www.uservoice.com/o/javascript-sdk
     //
     // Set colors
     UserVoice.push(['set', {
             accent_color: '#448dd6',
             trigger_color: 'white',
             trigger_background_color: 'rgba(46, 49, 51, 0.6)'
         }]);
     // Identify the user and pass traits
     // To enable, replace sample data with actual user traits and uncomment the line
     UserVoice.push(['identify', {
             //email:      'john.doe@example.com', // User’s email address
             //name:       'John Doe', // User’s real name
             //created_at: 1364406966, // Unix timestamp for the date the user signed up
             //id:         123, // Optional: Unique id of the user (if set, this should not change)
             //type:       'Owner', // Optional: segment your users by type
             //account: {
             //  id:           123, // Optional: associate multiple users with a single account
             //  name:         'Acme, Co.', // Account name
             //  created_at:   1364406966, // Unix timestamp for the date the account was created
             //  monthly_rate: 9.99, // Decimal; monthly rate of the account
             //  ltv:          1495.00, // Decimal; lifetime value of the account
             //  plan:         'Enhanced' // Plan name for the account
             //}
         }]);
     // Add default trigger to the bottom-right corner of the window:
     UserVoice.push(['addTrigger', {mode: 'contact', trigger_position: 'bottom-right'}]);
     // Or, use your own custom trigger:
     //UserVoice.push(['addTrigger', '#id', { mode: 'contact' }]);
     // Autoprompt for Satisfaction and SmartVote (only displayed under certain conditions)
     UserVoice.push(['autoprompt', {}]);
    });//ready
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400&display=swap&subset=cyrillic');
@font-face {
 font-family: 'fa-solid-900';
 font-display: swap;
 src: url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2) format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
 font-family: 'fa-brands-400';
 font-display: swap;
 src: url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

```html
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-number-3"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-number-3');
</script>
```

What should i do in order to fix those errors. This is my first try in PWA so i am lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up using [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/) and everything is working great now.

Comment: I met the similar problem with my PWA and Electron 11 after I upgraded Workbox from 5.1.3 to 6.3.0. See my repo: https://github.com/MrMYHuang/cbetar2/commit/214fd049cc66ab7f7015e4d3568b3706f0e8744b

Thanks for this answer. It suggests me to downgrade Workbox to fix this problem.